# Maven Dependency Class isn't resolving in project

Tags: java, maven-3, m2eclipse

I am updating an eclipse project to include a new dependency. I modified the pom.xml file to point to the 0.5 version (new) instead of the 0.4 (old). I can see the new 0.5 jar files in the Maven Dependencies list. I can open and view the classes and see the new, modified code for these files.

I now have errors on .java file in the main project. It isn't finding the new dependency to resolve its name. Is there something I'm missing? I've run Maven clean, rebuilt the indexes, rebooted my computer.

This is the pom.xml section. The 0.5 jar is saved locally in the m2 repository. It was imported from GITHUB and saved as a jar, then added into the project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>GWTCAL</groupId>
    <artifactId>GWT-CAL</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml? which is the dependency you are trying to upgrade?

Comment: updated with the dependency reference in the pom.xml

Comment: So its a local jar that is not available in the central maven repository. right?

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: I think you should install that jar to your `.m2` with the goal `install-file -Dfile=<path-to-your-jar-file> -DgroupId=GWTCAL -DartifactId=GWT-CAL -Dversion=0.9.5 -Dpackaging=jar`